# Electron cannot find module because of wrong path

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Im running a normal electron application, but when I run "npm start" it gives me the following error:

> Error: Cannot find module 'D:\General\projects\electron\cli.js'

But the app folder is `D:\General\projects\testProject` and there it is the node_modules... and all the required folders in my test project.

I've also tried installing globally and locally, updated npm and electron... but no results.
As far as I can see, the error is that electron is not looking at the correct path but, how could I change the path where it looks for the cli?

Comment: Can you share your start npm script ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, the directory had an special character at the name (`&`), so nodejs couldn't read the path correctly. I changed the name and now it works correctly.